# migrating erb to haml - strange behavior when using the build method with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml, nested-forms, erb

I have a simple view in Rails that I'm migrating from ERB to HAML. This view renders a nested form, but includes an empty child object it there aren't any existing child objects.

With ERB, I was accomplishing this by doing this:

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.object.answers.build if f.object.answers.empty? %>

  <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'answer_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works!  But when I do the same thing using HAML, it also "works", but prints an annoying text between the forms, something that looks like this: `#<Answer:0xb159004>`.

This is what my HAML looks like:

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

  = f.object.answers.build if f.object.answers.empty?

  = f.fields_for :answers do |builder|
    = render 'answer_fields', f: builder

  = f.submit
```

It is literally the same thing, but ERB works and HAML, although it works, it also prints `#<Answer:0xb159004>` near the forms, which I don't know how to get rid.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a HAML limitation/bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: can you post the code in your answer_fields template file?

Comment: Hi @Magicmarkker, the codes above are just an example to show this weird behavior. For this example, I actually used a very simple example from [railscast 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) to illustrate the problem. HAML still displays that `#<....>` string even if there isn't a fields_for or a render line.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I just have to replace the line that starts from "=" to "-", this way HAML won't insert the output! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem for many days, but after posting this, I had an insight and I fixed my own problem.

Replacing the beginning of the line from "=" to "-" fixes this, as this makes HAML not to insert the output of the ruby code.

```
= form_for @question do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

  - f.object.answers.build if f.object.answers.empty?    <--- fix

  = f.fields_for :answers do |builder|
    = render 'answer_fields', f: builder

  = f.submit
```

Every example I found on the web about this used ERB code in <%= syntax, and I assumed translating them to HAML were always just to remove <%, but not in this specific case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly resolve your question, but I always use http://html2haml.heroku.com/ for switching existing erb templates to HAML. Simply do a copy and paste of your existing erb code into the textfield and it'll output the corresponding HAML for you. It also accepts plain HTML. I've yet to see it spit out incorrect syntax so it's great for converting existing code without any divergency.